# Automated Backups From Windows To Remote Linux Server

Tags: linux, backup

I love rsync under Linux but Windows does not natively support it.

Is there any way to automate backups to a remote Linux Server from say...Server 2k3 or 2k8?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/win-rsync/

Comment: What Paul said, or look into robocopy.  Another very robust file copying/synchronizing tool.  It comes with WS2008 or you can download the Server 2003 Resource Kit which contains it.

Comment: Another option, especially useful if you can't or don't want to install software on the Windows machine(s) in question, is to install Samba on the Linux box and export the backup volume as an SMB share which you can mount via native Windows filesharing.

Answer (score 0):

I use [cwrsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) on Windows all the time, its a great product and syncs with Linux rsync perfectly.  You can run it as a service on the Windows machine or launch it in a script to connect to a Linux box.